# Conda env and python packages

Tags: python, unicode, anaconda, conda

I´m a newbie to conda, I only have a very surface-level understanding of how it works.
My objective was to install an annotation software (dammit) using conda. 
Conda was installed as follows:

```
wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O miniconda.sh && bash miniconda.sh -b -p $HOME/miniconda 
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/miniconda/bin:$PATH"' >> $HOME/.bashrc
```

Then I created an environment, set up the channels, and installed my software:

```
conda create -n dammit python=3 
source activate dammit

conda config --add channels defaults 
conda config --add channels conda-forge 
conda config --add channels bioconda 

conda install dammit
```

When I tried to run the main script an error occurred

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./dammit", line 5, in <module>
    from dammit import app
  File "/home/up201505534/miniconda/envs/dammit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dammit/app.py", line 13, in <module>
    from dammit import annotate
  File "/home/up201505534/miniconda/envs/dammit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dammit/annotate.py", line 13, in <module>
    from shmlast.app import CRBL
  File "/home/up201505534/miniconda/envs/dammit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/shmlast/app.py", line 3, in <module>
    from doit.tools import run_once, create_folder
  File "/home/up201505534/miniconda/envs/dammit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/doit/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from doit.doit_cmd import get_var
  File "/home/up201505534/miniconda/envs/dammit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/doit/doit_cmd.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .cmd_run import Run
  File "/home/up201505534/miniconda/envs/dammit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/doit/cmd_run.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .runner import Runner, MRunner, MThreadRunner
  File "/home/up201505534/miniconda/envs/dammit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/doit/runner.py", line 8, in <module>
    import cloudpickle
  File "/home/up201505534/miniconda/envs/dammit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cloudpickle/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from cloudpickle.cloudpickle import *
  File "/home/up201505534/miniconda/envs/dammit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py", line 61, in <module>
    import typing
  File "/opt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/typing.py", line 624, in <module>
    AnyStr = TypeVar('AnyStr', bytes, unicode)
```

It appears the problem is in the typing package in the python 2.7 libs. I have installed typing.py with conda in the dammit environment, however the same error occurs. How can I fix this, and have the "import command" to search in the dammit/lib/python lib instead?

Here is the sys.path:

```
['', '/opt/python', '/opt/lib64/python2.7/site-packages', '/opt/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/opt/lib64/python3.7/site-packages', '/opt/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/home/up201505534', '/home/up201505534/miniconda/envs/dammit/lib/python36.zip', '/home/up201505534/miniconda/envs/dammit/lib/python3.6', '/home/up201505534/miniconda/envs/dammit/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/up201505534/miniconda/envs/dammit/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

and the PYTHONPATH:

```
/opt/python:/opt/lib64/python2.7/site-packages:/opt/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/opt/lib64/python3.7/site-packages:/opt/lib/python3.7/site-packages:
```

Comment: Can you activate your `dammit` environment and give us the output of `python -c "import sys;print(sys.path)"` also `echo $PYTHONPATH`

Comment: added in the original post. I´m guessing that python searches in python2.7 library before the environment libraries. I should be able to manually edit the list order in the cloudpickle.py file, but is there a more robust method?

Comment: Did you set `PYTHONPATH` yourself? `PYTHONPATH` tells python interpreters additional paths where they can look for packages. I would recommend unsetting it (also check your bash startup files (e.g. ~/.bashrc), and only set it in the rare cases you know you need it. Here you allowed your python3 interpreter to find python2 libs which ended up in a mess.

Comment: Which installation instructions did you follow?

Comment: I installed like so: http://dib-lab.github.io/dammit/install/. Currently, I just set my pythonpath to check the env/dammit/lib/python3.6 for libraries first, but I have to export every time I use dammit (using .bashrc to export will set this library in the end of the PYTHONPATH variable, and as such does not solve the problem)